# How to filter an Eloquent collection within a certain number of days?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Eloquent model, Day, that contains an `activate_date` field which holds a Carbon object. I would like to return all of the days whose `activate_date` is within, for example, 7 days of today. I was trying to do it with a scope, but I can't seem to access the `activate_date` field within the scope function. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Post your code if you have it :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily:

```
$dateRef = new \Carbon::Carbon()
$dateRef->addDays(7);
// or $dateRef->subDays(7);

Day::where('activate_date', '<', $dateRef)->get();
```

with query scope:

```
public function scopeLast7Days($query)
{
    $dateRef = new \Carbon::Carbon()
    $dateRef->subDays(7);
    return $query->whereBetween('activate_date', [$dateRef, new \Carbon::Carbon()])
}

// use like this:
$days = Day::last7Days()->active()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```